# How do I type  on a keyboard?

Tags: cantonese, pinyin, traditional-characters, yale-romanization

I am using the Google Cantonese Input and Google Pinyin Input on my phone and cannot find a way to type .  Even when I switch to the handwriting method,  does not come up as an option and I get them separated as 門小 instead.

How would I type  with Pin Yin or Yale/Jyutping input?  For now, I'm just using 屌你 instead of 你.  Otherwise, I would have to copy and paste  and it gets annoying.

Comment: There is one thing you have to check first, does the input method you use really have the character? No IME can input any character, but only those built into the IME.

Comment: i am using lineage 18.1 with fdroid on android, and have been searching without success of a working Jyutping keyboard for android - multiling o keyboard does not seem to offer jyutping (or download missing), and the chinese plugin as separate download does not work - gboard is great but want to avoid google spying - openboard seems great for english but does not offer other languages so wondering if you masters out here have anything good to recommend that is independent/opensource or otherwise good Jyutping for android? many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character 「」 is in the Unicode CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B, which may not be supported by all operating systems and IMEs. Some IMEs support it but the feature is disabled by default.

For a Cangjie IME that supports *extension B*, the code is `日弓火` (`anf`).

Answer (score 3):

One could always argue that if you find it annoying to copy/paste , you're using it too much, and should clean up your vocabulary :-)

It all depends on the platform you're using. I'm on a Mac (laptop) and Android (phone/tablet). On my Mac, I have customized an old [Jyutping IME by Dominic Yu](http://blyt.net/domingo2/Chinese.html), based on the LSHK table. I added  (and many other things) to the IME. You can get it [here](https://github.com/dda/jyutping).

On my Android, I use MultiLing, which is good in most cases, but its fuzzy logic makes it very hard to input single-syllable words that are not common (at least in their idea of common). I usually resort, for such characters, to trying first pinyin, then Japanese, or, if everything fails, hand-writing.

## EDIT

On MultiLing, typing `diunei` gives 屌你, which is the fastest way I found to type 屌 – if 你 isn't needed just erase it.

Comment: I just wonder what sort of writings that require the use of this word that often? It's certainly not for children.

Comment: HK people tend to be quite foul-mouthed...

Answer (score 0):

The character is not supported by most of the fonts and IMEs. You can set up a proper font or just type "屌" (Pinyin: diao，Jyutping: diu) instead.

The Cangjie IME KH.Lee referred to is an IME that supports over 70,000 characters. You have to have a good understanding of the structure of a character before you type it correctly.

Cangjie is provided in Windows and Mac OS and is widely used in Hong Kong and Macau for most people have not learned Pinyin or Jyutping.

Answer (score -2):

Use the handwriting keyboard or 屌 is fine.